# ActiveAdmin has_many with custom collection order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeadmin

Given the following models:

```
class WorkoutProgram < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :workouts, dependent: :destroy
end

class Workout < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :workout_program
end
```

Is there any way to set a custom order in ActiveAdmin has_many input? I don't want to enable drag & drop so `sortable` is not an option. The idea is to show the workouts in the same order they were added when editing a `WorkoutProgram`.

As a *workaround* I am using another has_many relation in `WorkoutProgram` only for this purpose. So I added to the model:

```
has_many :ordered_workouts, -> { ordered_by_id },
           class_name: Workout.to_s, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :workout_program
```

and then used it in the ActiveAdmin page like this:

```
form.has_many :ordered_workouts, allow_destroy: true do...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
form.has_many :workouts, for: [:workouts, form.object.workouts.ordered_by_id] #, ...
```